# How to use c# login wordpress

Tags: c#, wordpress, authentication

This example login function **But does not work for loading the Dashboard page** wordpress. 
I need to perform some action in wordpress admin panel programmatically but can't manage how to login to Wordpress using C# and HttpWebRequest.

Here is what I do:

```
namespace Wordpress_Login
{
    public class WPWorkerTests
    {
        CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        public String StartAdmin()
        {
           //string wp_url = "http://localhost/wp";
           string admin_url = "http://localhost/wp/wp-admin";
           string login_url = "http://localhost/wp/wp-login.php";
           string post_data = "log=test&pwd=asdfz&rememberme=forever&wp-submit=Log+In&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fwp%2Fwp-admin%2F&testcookie=1";

           HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(login_url);
           request1.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
           request1.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0";
           request1.KeepAlive = true; //this is the default
           request1.ContentType = "text/html";
           request1.Timeout = 10000;
           request1.Method = "GET";
           HttpWebResponse response1 = (HttpWebResponse)request1.GetResponse();
           StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response1.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
           //MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());

           HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(login_url);
           request2.Method = "POST";
           request2.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
           request2.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0";
           request2.KeepAlive = true;
           request2.Timeout = 100000;
           request2.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
           request2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
           byte[] byteArray2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data);
           request2.ContentLength = byteArray2.Length;
           Stream dataStream2 = request2.GetRequestStream();
           dataStream2.Write(byteArray2, 0, byteArray2.Length);
           dataStream2.Close();
           HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();
           //MessageBox.Show(((HttpWebResponse)response2).StatusDescription);
           dataStream2 = response2.GetResponseStream();
           StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(dataStream2);
           string report2 = reader2.ReadToEnd();
           //MessageBox.Show(report2);
           reader2.Close();
           dataStream2.Close();
           response2.Close();

           HttpWebRequest request3 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(admin_url);
           request3.Method = "GET";
           request3.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
           request3.ContentType = "text/html";
           request3.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0";
           request3.KeepAlive = true;
           request3.Timeout = 100000;
           request3.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
           HttpWebResponse response3 = (HttpWebResponse)request3.GetResponse();
           StreamReader sr3 = new StreamReader(response3.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
           string report3 = sr3.ReadToEnd();
           return report3;
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately in responce I get only HTML source code of login page and it seems that cookies don't contain session ID. All requests which I perform after that code also return HTML source of login page so I can assume that it does not login correctly.

Comment: Is this something you couldn't do using the xml-rpc API -- http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API ; even if it is I would look at writing a wordpress plugin to take remote requests and not screen scraping as that will break. Most likely when you are on your dream vacation.

Comment: xml-rpc API can not log into Dashboard, or turn off plug-ins.

Comment: Gotcha. I'd run with a custom plugin first. Another option would be just disabling the plugins on the mysql level, that is a pretty straightforward operation as well.